# How to set NSPopUpButton's menu's position?

Tags: macos, cocoa, menu, nsmenu, nspopupbutton

I need to set a custom position to the `NSMenu` of a `NSPopUpButton` object.
The default position looks like this:

[image]

But I want it to look like this:

[image]

Comment: Just in case you don't *need* to use a NSMenu could could consider using a the button to trigger an NSPopover. Although this still doesn't give you customisation of where it appears (as you have draw it).

Answer (score -1):

You'll have to roll your own - there's no (public) API to control that aspect of a Cocoa `NSPopupButton`.

Comment: I see :( Any thought on how I can roll my on?